# Menu items to come one below the other in media response using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items and I have used the toggle to appear when the media resolution is at 768px. The list was coming in one column and now I made it display in a row. As I have 5 lists in my menu I want 2 lists to appear in one row at 360px resolution and at 640px resolution 4 items can be shown in a row. so based on the resolution width it must take lists in a row and rest as dropdown rows.

```css
.leftSide ul:first-child li a{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 20px 62px;
      color:red;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family:segoeuib;
      font-size:16px;
}

.leftSide ul {
  margin: 0px;
}

.leftSide ul:first-child li a:hover,.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #b755ff !important ;
  background-color: white !important;
}
li.fav a:hover {
  margin-left: 9px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:768px) { 
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  span.caret.arrow {
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: 58px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left leftSide">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Browse<span class="caret arrow"></span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Interviews</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
         <li class="fav"><a href="#">My Favourites</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: you added `Flex` in media still is not working?

Comment: it is coming in a row, but i need them to come according to width of the resolution

Comment: use `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: ya thank you,it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `flex-basis` property to your `menu>li` according to your requirement. Try below css.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.nav.navbar-nav.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .menu li {
    flex-basis: 25%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:360px) {
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .menu li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left leftSide">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Interviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
    <li class="fav"><a href="#">My Favourites</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is working according to my requirement. I have one more doubt.

Comment: it is with responsive of this menu list items only. In media @768px and below i get toggle so it works fine, but above that resolution i am struggling a lot with header full thing. Can you help me

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I will suggest you to post an another question with minimal and complete code with your issues. It will be difficult to solve your others problem here. I hope you will understand...

Comment: I had posted already in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300599/how-to-use-navigation-bar-for-website-by-making-middle-div-to-vary-using-html-an